# Append variable to end of each result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter for my framework and I have went over the documentation and I have not found a solution.

Now that I have the the data selected from the database I need to get the distance to be displayed at the end of each record retrieved.

```
Example of json: {"details":[{"country":"United States","_id":"3892","lat":"39.954559","lng":"-82.837608","admin_level_1":"Ohio","locale":"Columbus"}]}
```

This is what it needs to be, keep in mind that distance is not in the database, it is calculated on the fly.

```
Example of json: {"details":[{"country":"United States","_id":"3892","lat":"39.954559","lng":"-82.837608","admin_level_1":"Ohio","locale":"Columbus", "distance": "1.2 Mi"}]}
```

Any ideas on how to get ths distance that is caculcated to be appended to the end of each result?

```
        $dbStations->select('lat');
        $dbStations->select('lng');
        $dbStations->select('_id');
        $stations = $dbStations->get('stDetails');
        foreach ($stations->result() as $station) {
            $lat2 = $station->lat;
            $lng2 = $station->lng;
            $stId = $station->_id;
            $distance = $this->distance->gpsdistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, "M");
                if ($distance <= $rad) {
                //at this point the code has determined that this id is within
                //the preferred distance.
                $stationArr[] = $stId;
            }
        }
            $dbStations->select('country, _id, lat, lng, admin_level_1, locale');
            $dbStations->where_in('_id', $stationArr);
            $stations = $dbStations->get('stationDetails');
        echo json_encode(array('stations' => $stations->result()));
    }
```

Comment: Are `$dbStations->get('stDetails')` and `$dbStations->get('stationDetails')` supposed to be querying the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do everything at once. This query should give you the stations within the radius `$rad`, according to what is possible to know your table.

The variables `$lat1` and `$lng1` must be defined.

```
$query= "select country, _id, lat, lng, admin_level_1, locale, 
    (acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + cos(radians($lat1)) *
    cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians($lng1) - radians(lng))) * 6378)
     as distance
    from stationDetails
    where (acos(sin(radians($lat1)) * sin(radians(lat)) + 
          cos(radians($lat1)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians($lng1) - 
          radians(lng))) * 6378)<=$rad
    order by distance desc";

echo json_encode($this->db->query($query)->result_array());
```

**Note:** The distance is in meters.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I have used it as a query and it repsonds fast and effective. This is what I was looking for. I did not know I could use those commands in a MySQL Query.

Comment: MySQL is rich in features that used little. You can read some more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$dbStations->get('stDetails')` and `$dbStations->get('stationDetails')` are querying the same table, you could do something like this:

```
$dbStations->select('country, _id, lat, lng, admin_level_1, locale');
$stations = $dbStations->get('stDetails');

$output = array();

foreach ($stations->result() as $station) {
    $lat2 = $station->lat;
    $lng2 = $station->lng;

    $distance = $this->distance->gpsdistance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, "M");

    if ($distance <= $rad) {
        $station->distance = $distance;
        $output[] = $station;
    }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

I haven't tested this and it may not give you exactly what you want so you may have to tweak it a little bit.  The important thing is how I am doing it.  Grab all the data at the beginning and and then validate each row.  If the row is valid (within a certain distance), add the distance to the array and save it to be outputted.  When there are no more rows left, output the valid stations.

Comment: I get this error when trying this code:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Change `$station['distance'] = $distance` to `$station->distance = $distance`.

Comment: This however worked but querying all that data overloads the memory causing errors with php. Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 45088768) (tried to allocate 32 bytes). I've changed the PHP file but I don't want to keep it with that big of a buffer. In addition this method call is slower. I prefer @Alfonso Rubalcava method better, even though it is a long query, lol.